# How to cancel IMvxAsyncCommand?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I just started using xamarin android with MVVMcross platform. I need to cancel an IMvxAsyncCommand but I try a lot of way, it still not work. Does anyone have any ideas or sample of this?

Comment: Hey Huy! Welcome to SO! The way I did it yesterday was to simply add a return at the beginning of the function call. But what will really help us is if you share some of your code in the question. Here's a good article to read that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually cancel a `MvxAsyncCommand` directly without creating any additional `CancellationTokenSource`.

Just call `Cancel()` on the object itself.

So instead of having the property being `ICommand` or `IMvxCommand` use `MvxAsyncCommand` or `IMvxAsyncCommand`.

This way when you have a `CancellationToken` as argument in your `Task` and you call `Cancel()` on the command, it will cancel that token.

```cs
private async Task MyAsyncStuff(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await abc.AwesomeAsyncMethod(ct);
    // and/or
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

So if you modify @fmaccaroni's answer, you will get this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{    
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyAsyncCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(MyAsyncStuff);
        CancelMyTaskCommand = new MvxCommand(() => MyAsyncCommand.Cancel());
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand {get; private set; }

    public ICommand CancelMyTaskCommand { get; private set; }

    private async Task MyAsyncStuff(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await foo.BlablaAsync();

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await bar.WhateverAsync();

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await foo2.AnotherAsync();
    }
}
```

EDIT: or even better if your async methods also allow passing along the `CancellationToken` cancelling them directly, the `MyAsyncStuff` method could be written like:

```cs
private async Task MyAsyncStuff(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await foo.BlablaAsync(cancellationToken);
    await bar.WhateverAsync(cancellationToken);
    await foo2.AnotherAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Or if you don't care which order they get started and complete in:

```cs
private Task MyAsyncStuff(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        foo.BlablaAsync(cancellationToken),
        bar.WhateverAsync(cancellationToken),
        foo2.AnotherAsync(cancellationToken));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically a `IMvxAsyncCommand` just calls a `Task` like this:

```cs
MyCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(MyTask);
...
private async Task MyTask()
{
     // do async stuff
}
```

In order to cancel a `Task` you need to use a `CancellationToken`, which you can get it from a `CancellationTokenSource` and use another command or whatever you want to call the `Cancel()` on the `CancellationTokenSource`, so one way you could do it would be:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyAsyncCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(MyTask);
        CancelMyTaskCommand = new MvxCommand(() => cts.Cancel());
    }

    public ICommand MyAsyncCommand {get; private set; }

    public ICommand CancelMyTaskCommand { get; private set; }

    private async Task MyTask()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await MyAsyncStuff(cts.CancellationToken);

        cts.Dispose();
        cts = null;
    }

    private async Task MyAsyncStuff(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await foo.BlablaAsync();

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await bar.WhateverAsync();

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await foo2.AnotherAsync();
    }
}
```

You can then improve the code to avoid duplicate calls to the `Task`, handle the cancellation exception, use an [MvxNotifyTask](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/mvxnotifytask) and many other things but this is the basics.

More info in [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)
HIH